# Error en CSS Button Menu en el navegador de iPad o iPhone

Tags: css

Estoy utilizando en un proyecto personal una serie de botones desplegables con un menú interno, el problema radica en que al abrir estos botones desde un navegador de un dispositivo de Apple (hemos probado con Safari y Chrome y en los dos falla) cuando pulsas en esos links no se ejecuta el :focus y no se lanza las animaciones ni se abre el menú.

Se puede ver un ejemplo aquí https://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/zvOvoY

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
[class*="fab"] {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.fab-shadow {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 400;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0s 0.5s;
}
.fab-button {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 16px;
  display: table;
  background: #2196f3;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: relative;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}
.fab-button.red {
  background: #f44336;
}
.fab-button.pink {
  background: #e91e63;
}
.fab-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.fab-button:focus {
  z-index: 450;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.fab-button:focus ~ .fab-shadow {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0s;
}
.fab-button div {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 29px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 -11px #fff, 0 11px #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 1);
}
.fab-button:focus .dot {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 -3px #fff, 0 3px #fff, -3px 0 #fff, 3px 0 #fff, 0 -6px #fff, 0 6px #fff, -6px 0 #fff, 6px 0 #fff, 0 -9px #fff, 0 9px #fff, -9px 0 #fff, 9px 0 #fff, 0 -12px #fff, 0 12px #fff, -12px 0 #fff, 12px 0 #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.fab-button .plus {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 -3px #fff, 0 3px #fff, -3px 0 #fff, 3px 0 #fff, 0 -6px #fff, 0 6px #fff, -6px 0 #fff, 6px 0 #fff, 0 -9px #fff, 0 9px #fff, -9px 0 #fff, 9px 0 #fff, 0 -12px #fff, 0 12px #fff, -12px 0 #fff, 12px 0 #fff;
}
.fab-button:focus .plus {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.fab-button .menu {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: -12px -9px #fff, -9px -9px #fff, -6px -9px #fff, -3px -9px #fff, 0 -9px #fff, 3px -9px #fff, 6px -9px #fff, 9px -9px #fff, 12px -9px #fff, -12px 0 #fff, -9px 0 #fff, -6px 0 #fff, -3px 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 3px 0 #fff, 6px 0 #fff, 9px 0 #fff, 12px 0 #fff, -12px 9px #fff, -9px 9px #fff, -6px 9px #fff, -3px 9px #fff, 0 9px #fff, 3px 9px #fff, 6px 9px #fff, 9px 9px #fff, 12px 9px #fff;
}
.fab-button:focus .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 -12px #fff, 0 -9px #fff, 0 -6px #fff, 0 -3px #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 -3px #fff, 0 -6px #fff, 0 -9px #fff, 0 -12px #fff, -12px 0 #fff, -9px 0 #fff, -6px 0 #fff, -3px 0 #fff, 0 0 #fff, 3px 0 #fff, 6px 0 #fff, 9px 0 #fff, 12px 0 #fff, 0 12px #fff, 0 9px #fff, 0 6px #fff, 0 3px #fff, 0 0 #fff, 0 3px #fff, 0 6px #fff, 0 9px #fff, 0 12px #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.fab-button:focus + .fab-options,
.fab-options:active {
  width: auto;
  overflow: initial;
}
.fab-options {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: -8px 0 0 20px;
}
.fab-options .fab-option {
  display: table;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 8px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.fab-options .fab-option * {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}
.fab-options .fab-option:hover * {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.fab-options .fab-option p {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #424242;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.fab-options .fab-option i {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #424242;
}
```

```html
<a class="fab-button" href="">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</a>
<div class="fab-options">
  <a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i>
    <p>
      Refresh
    </p>
  </a><a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">help</i>
    <p>
      Support
    </p>
  </a><a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">info</i>
    <p>
      Documantation
    </p>
  </a><a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>
    <p>
      Settings
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<a class="fab-button red" href="">
  <div class="plus"></div>
</a>
<div class="fab-options">
  <a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">insert_drive_file</i>
    <p>
      New File
    </p>
  </a><a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">folder</i>
    <p>
      New Folder
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<a class="fab-button pink" href="">
  <div class="menu"></div>
</a>
<div class="fab-options">
  <a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i>
    <p>
      Home
    </p>
  </a><a class="fab-option" href="#"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
    <p>
      About Us
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="fab-shadow"></div>
```

Hemos probado de todo ya y por desconocimiento de las reglas de excepción de estos dispositivos de Apple no somos capaces de solucionar este problema.

Agradecemos por adelantado su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que es un problema conocido que se soluciona incluyendo un `ontouchstart=""` vacío en el `body`:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

Entiendo que será un problema del renderizador de Safari pendiente de solucionar.

La solución está sacada de otras respuestas del sitio de SO en inglés:

[:active pseudo-class doesn't work in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari)

[CSS :focus Not Working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584335/css-focus-not-working-in-ios)

Comment: Gracias Asier por tu respuesta, pero desafortunadamente no nos funciona esa solución.